# A canonical way to implement move semantics in a class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am looking for a good example of how to implement a derived and a base class with move semantics.  The more I have thought about it, the more it seems that the default move constructor and assignment move operator will normally do the job because most standard (STL) types and smart pointers are default moveable.

Anyway, in the case we have a class hierarchy, which requires an explicit move implementation, how should I do it - at least as a first cut?

In this example, I am using a raw pointer which I would normally wrap in a std::unique_ptr but I needed an example of something to move which is not default moveable.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Currently, I have made the following attempt:

```
struct BlobA
{
    char data[0xaa];
};

struct BlobB
{
    char data[0xbb];
};

//----------------------------------------

class Base
{
public:

    //Default construct the Base class
    //C++11 allows the data members to initialised, where declared. Otherwise you would do it here.
    Base()
    {

    }

    //Define the destructor as virtual to ensure that the derived destructor gets called. (In case it is necessary. It's not in this example but still good practice.)
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        delete m_moveableDataInBase; //this is a contrived example to show non-default moveable data, in practice RAII should be used rather than deletes like this
    }

    //Copy constructor, needs to accept a const ref to another Base class with which it copies the data members
    Base(const Base& other) :
    m_moveableDataInBase(new BlobA(*other.m_moveableDataInBase)), // copy the other's moveable data
    m_pNonMoveableDataInBase(other.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase)        // copy the other's non-moveable data
    {

    }

    //Assignment operator uses the canonical copy then swap idiom. It returns a reference to allow chaining: a = b = c
    //This is thus implemented in terms of the copy constructor.
    Base& operator=(const Base& rhs)
    {
        Base temp(rhs);
        Swap(temp);
        return *this;
    }

    //The move construtor is declared as throwing no exceptions so that it will be called by STL algorithms
    //It accepts an rvalue and moves the Base part.
    Base(Base&& other) noexcept :
    m_moveableDataInBase(nullptr) // don't bother allocating our own resources to moveable data because we are about to move (steal) the other's resource
    {
        Swap(other);
    }

    //The move assignment operator is declared as throwing no exceptions so that it will be called by STL algorithms
    //It accepts an rvalue and moves (steals) the data resources from the rhs using swap and copies the non moveable data from the rhs
    Base& operator=(Base&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        //move (steal) the moveable contents from rhs
        std::swap(m_moveableDataInBase, rhs.m_moveableDataInBase);

        //copy the non-moveable contents from rhs
        m_pNonMoveableDataInBase = rhs.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase;

        return *this;
    }

private:
    //this private member swaps the data members' contents.
    //It is private because it isn't virtual and only swaps the base contents and is thus not safe as a public interface
    void Swap(Base& other)
    {
        std::swap(m_moveableDataInBase, other.m_moveableDataInBase);
        std::swap(m_pNonMoveableDataInBase, other.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase);
    }

    //an example of some large blob of data which we would like to move instead of copy for performance reasons.
    //normally, I would have used a unique_ptr but this is default moveable and I need an example of something that isn't
    BlobA* m_moveableDataInBase{ new BlobA };

    //an example of some data that we can't or don't want to move
    int m_pNonMoveableDataInBase = 123;
};

//----------------------------------------

class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    //Default construct the Derived class, this is called after the base class constructor
    //C++11 allows the data members to initialised, where declared. Otherwise you would do it here.
    Derived()
    {

    }

    //Default virtual destructor, to clean up stuff that can't be done automatically through RAII
    virtual ~Derived()
    {
        delete m_pMoveableDataInDerived; //this is a contrived example to show non-default moveable data, in practice RAII should be used rather than deletes like this
    }

    //Copy constructor, needs to accept a const ref to another derived class with which it
    //first copy constructs the base and then copies the derived data members
    Derived(const Derived& other) :
    Base(other),  // forward to the base copy constructor
    m_pMoveableDataInDerived(new BlobB(*other.m_pMoveableDataInDerived)),  // copy the other's moveable data
    m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived(other.m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived)         // copy the other's non-moveable data
    {

    }

    //Assignment operator uses the canonical copy then swap idiom. It returns a reference to allow chaining: a = b = c
    //Because it uses the derived copy constructor, which in turn copy constructs the base, we don't forward to the base assignment operator.
    Derived& operator=(const Derived& rhs)
    {
        Derived temp(rhs);
        Swap(temp);
        return *this;
    }

    //The move construtor is declared as throwing no eceptions so that it will be called by STL algorithms
    //It accepts an rvalue and first moves the Base part and then the Derived part.
    //There is no point in allocating any resource before moving so in this example, m_pBlobB is set to nullptr
    Derived(Derived&& other) noexcept
    : Base(std::move(other)), // forward to base move constructor
    m_pMoveableDataInDerived(nullptr) // don't bother allocating our own resources to moveable data because we are about to move (steal) the other's resource
    {
        Swap(other);
    }

    //The move assignment operator is declared as throwing no exceptions so that it will be called by STL algorithms
    //It accepts an rvalue and first calls the base assignment operator and then moves the data resources from the rhs using swap
    Derived& operator=(Derived&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        //forward to the base move operator=
        Base::operator=(std::move(rhs));

        //move (steal) the moveable contents from rhs
        std::swap(m_pMoveableDataInDerived, rhs.m_pMoveableDataInDerived);

        //copy the non-moveable contents from rhs
        m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived = rhs.m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived;
    }

private:
    //this member swaps the Derived data members contents.
    //It is private because it doesn't swap the base contents and is thus not safe as a public interface
    void Swap(Derived& other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(m_pMoveableDataInDerived, other.m_pMoveableDataInDerived);
        std::swap(m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived, other.m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived);
    }

    //an example of some large blob of data which we would like to move instead of copy for performance reasons.
    //normally, I would have used a unique_ptr but this is default moveable and I need an example of something that isn't
    BlobB* m_pMoveableDataInDerived{ new BlobB };

    //an example of some data that we can't or don't want to move
    int m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived = 456;
};
```

Comment: Have you considered using `unique_ptr<Bla>` for the movable data pointer? Then you get a lot of your semantics "for free"

Comment: @M.M, yes, I pointed this out in my question, if you could take the time to read it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say in your sentence containing the word "unique_ptr". Are you saying you choose not to use unique_ptr even though you know it would solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

You have to start out knowing what your class invariants are.  A class invariant is something or some relationship that is always true among your data members.  And then you want to make sure that your special members can operate with any value which satisfies your class invariants.  Special members should not have preconditions (except that all class invariants must be true).

Let's take your example as an example case to discuss.  First lets just concentrate on `Base`.  I like to put my private data members up front so that they are close to the special members.  This way I can more easily see what defaulted or implicitly declared special members actually do.

**Base**

```
class Base
{
    //an example of some large blob of data which we would like to move 
    //  instead of copy for performance reasons.
    //normally, I would have used a unique_ptr but this is default moveable
    //   and I need an example of something that isn't
    BlobA* m_moveableDataInBase{ new BlobA };

    //an example of some data that we can't or don't want to move
    int m_pNonMoveableDataInBase = 123;
```

So far so good, but there is a *slight* ambiguity here:  Can `m_moveableDataInBase == nullptr`?  There is no one right or wrong answer.  This is a question that the author of `Base` must answer, and then write code to enforce.

Also, outline your member functions.  Even if you decide you want to inline them, do so outside the declaration.  Otherwise your class declaration becomes difficult to read:

```
class Base
{
    BlobA* m_moveableDataInBase{ new BlobA };
    int m_pNonMoveableDataInBase = 123;

public:
    virtual ~Base();
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base& other);
    Base& operator=(const Base& rhs);
    Base(Base&& other) noexcept;
    Base& operator=(Base&& rhs) noexcept;
};
```

The destructor is the most telling special member.  I like to get it declared/defined first:

```
Base::~Base()
{
    delete m_moveableDataInBase;
}
```

This looks good.  But this does not yet answer the question as to whether `m_moveableDataInBase` can be `nullptr`.  Next, if it exists, the default constructor.  Prefer `= default` definitions when practical.

Now the copy constructor:

```
Base::Base(const Base& other)
    : m_moveableDataInBase(new BlobA(*other.m_moveableDataInBase))
    , m_pNonMoveableDataInBase(other.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase)
{
}
```

Ok, this says something significant:

```
other.m_moveableDataInBase != nullptr  // ever
```

I glanced ahead and looked at your move constructor, and that leaves the moved-from value with `m_moveableDataInBase == nullptr`.  So we have a problem:

1. Either there is a bug in your copy constructor, and you should check for the case `other.m_moveableDataInBase == nullptr`, or
2. There is a bug in your move constructor and it should not leave the moved-from state with `m_moveableDataInBase == nullptr`.

Neither solution is the correct one.  The `Base` author has to make this design decision.  If he choses 2, there really is no reasonable way to implement the move constructor such that it is any faster than the copy constructor.  In that case the thing to do is not write a move constructor and just let the copy constructor do the job.  So I'll choose 1 so that there is still a move constructor to talk about.  Corrected copy constructor:

```
Base::Base(const Base& other)
    : m_moveableDataInBase(other.m_moveableDataInBase ?
                           new BlobA(*other.m_moveableDataInBase) :
                           nullptr)
    , m_pNonMoveableDataInBase(other.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase)
{
}
```

Also, since we chose this invariant, it might not be a bad idea to revisit the default constructor and instead say:

```
    BlobA* m_moveableDataInBase = nullptr;
```

Now we have a `noexcept` default constructor.

Next comes the copy assignment operator.  Do not fall into the trap of selecting the copy/swap idiom by default.  Sometimes this idiom is fine.  But it is often poorly performing.  [And performance is more important than code reuse](http://howardhinnant.github.io/coding_guidelines.html).  Consider this alternative to copy/swap:

```
Base&
Base::operator=(const Base& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        if (m_moveableDataInBase == nullptr)
        {
            if (rhs.m_moveableDataInBase != nullptr)
                m_moveableDataInBase = new BlobA(*rhs.m_moveableDataInBase);
        }
        else  // m_moveableDataInBase != nullptr
        {
            if (rhs.m_moveableDataInBase != nullptr)
                *m_moveableDataInBase = *rhs.m_moveableDataInBase;
            else
            {
                delete m_moveableDataInBase;
                m_moveableDataInBase = nullptr;
            }
        }
        m_pNonMoveableDataInBase = rhs.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

If it is common for values of `Base` to have `m_moveableDataInBase != nullptr`, then this rewrite is significantly faster than copy/swap.  In this common case, copy/swap always does 1 new and 1 delete.  This version does 0 news and 0 deletes.  It just copies 170 bytes.

And if we had chosen the design where it is an invariant that `m_moveableDataInBase != nullptr`, then the copy assignment gets even simpler:

```
Base&
Base::operator=(const Base& rhs)
{
    *m_moveableDataInBase = *rhs.m_moveableDataInBase;
    m_pNonMoveableDataInBase = rhs.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase;
    return *this;
}
```

Minimizing calls to the heap is *not* premature optimization.  It is engineering.  It is what move semantics is made out of.  This is *precisely* why `std::vector` and `std::string` copy assignment do not use the copy/swap idiom.  It would be too slow.

Move constructor:  I would code it like this:

```
Base::Base(Base&& other) noexcept
    : m_moveableDataInBase(std::move(other.m_moveableDataInBase))
    , m_pNonMoveableDataInBase(std::move(other.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase))
{
    other.m_moveableDataInBase = nullptr;
}
```

This saves a few loads and stores.  I didn't bother inspecting the generated assembly.  I urge you to do so before choosing your implementation over this one.  In a `noexcept` move constructor, count loads and stores.

As a style-guide, I like to `move` the members even when I know they are scalars and the move has no impact.  This saves the reader of the code from having to ensure that all non-moved members are scalars.

Your move assignment looks fine to me:

```
Base&
Base::operator=(Base&& rhs) noexcept
{
    //move (steal) the moveable contents from rhs
    std::swap(m_moveableDataInBase, rhs.m_moveableDataInBase);
    //copy the non-moveable contents from rhs
    m_pNonMoveableDataInBase = rhs.m_pNonMoveableDataInBase;
    return *this;
}
```

The one time when you don't want to do this is when you have non-memory resources on the lhs that need to be destructed immediately, as opposed to swapped to the rhs.  But your example is only swapping memory.

**Derived**

For `Derived` I would write it exactly as I've shown for `Base`, except for first copying/moving the `Base` exactly as you show in your code.  For example here is the move constructor:

```
Derived::Derived(Derived&& other) noexcept
    : Base(std::move(other))
    , m_pMoveableDataInDerived(std::move(other.m_pMoveableDataInDerived))
    , m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived(std::move(other.m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived))
{
    other.m_pMoveableDataInDerived = nullptr;
}
```

Also tag `~Dervied()` with `override` instead of `virtual`.  You want the compiler to tell you if you've accidentally somehow not overridden `~Base()` with `~Derived()`.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    BlobB* m_pMoveableDataInDerived = nullptr;
    int m_pNonMoveableDataInDerived = 456;

public:
    ~Derived() override;
    Derived() = default;
    Derived(const Derived& other);
    Derived& operator=(const Derived& rhs);
    Derived(Derived&& other) noexcept;
    Derived& operator=(Derived&& rhs) noexcept;
};
```

**Test**

Also test all six special members (whether you have them or not) with `static_assert` and type-traits:

```
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<Base>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<Base>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Base>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<Base>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Base>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<Base>{}, "");

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible<Derived>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<Derived>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Derived>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<Derived>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Derived>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<Derived>{}, "");
```

You can even test these for your `Blob` types:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<BlobA>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_default_constructible<BlobA>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<BlobA>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable<BlobA>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_constructible<BlobA>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_assignable<BlobA>{}, "");

static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<BlobB>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_default_constructible<BlobB>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<BlobB>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable<BlobB>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_constructible<BlobB>{}, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_assignable<BlobB>{}, "");
```

**Summary**

In summary, give each of the six special members all the loving care they deserve, even if the result is to inhibit them, implicitly declare them, or explicitly default or delete them.  The complier-generated move members will move each base, then move each non-static data member.  Prefer that recipe, default it when you can, and simply augment it when it is necessary.

Highlight your class API by moving member function definitions out of the class declaration.

Test.  At the very least test that you do or do not have all 6 special members, and if you have them, if they are `noexcept` or trivial (or not).

Use copy/swap with caution.  It can be a performance killer.

Answer (score 3):

> Anyway, in the case we have a class hierarchy, which requires an
>   explicit move implementation, how should I do it - at least as a first
>   cut?

Don't.

You don't move the base class. You move the pointer to the base class. For the derived class, you can move it but then you know what the derived class is so you can just write the move constructor/assignment operator accordingly.

Also, raw pointers are completely movable. How do you think `unique_ptr` is implemented?

Comment: thanks for your response. If I move the derived class then I need to move the resources both in the derived and the base class. I have no pointer to the base class, it shares the memory of the derived class. e.g. Derived d1; auto d2(std::move(d1));   The default move constructor will not move the memory that the pointer is pointing to, it will simply copy the pointer. std::unique_ptr when moved will point to the other's memory and set the other's pointer to nullptr.

Comment: That's what a custom move constructor is for. You can trivially set the other pointer to null in your move constructor.

Comment: That is what my attempt above is doing and what I am looking for advice on especially in the context of derived and base classes.

Comment: Then I don't see what the problem is. You've already found and implemented the solution. Derived and base class doesn't change or really matter anything in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch the "swap with other" approach which doesn't help with the readablity and go with simple assignments instead.

```
class A{
   int * dataA;
   public:
   A() { dataA = new int(); }
   virtual ~A() {delete dataA; }
   A(A&& rhs) noexcept { dataA = rhs.dataA; rhs.dataA = nullptr; } 
   A& operator = (A&& rhs) noexcept {
      if (this != &rhs){
       if (dataA) delete  dataA; 
       dataA = rhs.dataA;
       rhs.dataA = nullptr;
      }
      return *this;
   } 
}

class B: public A{
   int* dataB;
   public:    
       B(){ dataB = new int(); }
       virtual ~B() {delete dataB; }
       B(B&& rhs) noexcept : A(std::move(rhs)) { dataB = rhs.dataB; rhs.dataB = nullptr; }  

   B& operator = (B&& rhs) noexcept {
      A::operator == (std::move(rhs));
      if (this != &rhs){           
      if (dataB) delete  dataB; 
      dataB = rhs.dataB;
      rhs.dataB = nullptr;
      }
      return *this;
   }
}
```

call the parent move constructor to move the parent-part of the object. do the rest in the move constructor.

the same goes for the assignment operator.

Comment: Thanks David for your feedback. The reason I used swap idiom is because this is the canonical way of implementing operator= and there is now shared code. It also works with moving to self. For example, your code would break with: B d; d = std::move(d);    There are some other issues in your implementation but I think they are just typos.

Comment: anyay, there is no such thing "Cannocal way". the "cannonical way" is to shallow copy the content of rhs and invalidate rhs in a way that rhs destructor can destruct it safetly. who told you that "swap(other)" is a "cannonical" way?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo, although you also misspelled it! ;-) . Swap is canonical for implementing operator= in terms of copy constructor. I took the liberty of using it for implementing the move semantics also but I am not 100% certain that this is the best approach which is basically what I am asking for help with.